Gmail App "View entire message" Breaking Email
I've had to dive back into HTML email development after a good few years of (blissfully) not having to develop any emails as my employer wants a new email template for us to use. I've got the email template working via the DotDigital platform on most clients but the one that is giving me grief is the Gmail app's "View entire message" mode that it uses when it clips longer emails. These emails tend to be long as they're newsletters which (rightly or wrongly) contain a lot of information and offers, so they need to be compatible with this mode.
My email template looks fine (not perfect yet, but getting there) when I'm viewing it in the core app (see: Image 1) but when I click the "View entire message" link and it opens it up (see: Image 2) everything looks broken - like it's ignoring the responsiveness that I've developed into the email.
Gmail App

Gmail App - "View entire message"

Does anyone have an idea as to why it's doing this? Does this mode in Gmail have certain quirks I'm not familiar with, such as stripping out responsive code? It's frustrating as hell and I'm not sure what could be the issue.
Thanks in advance!

This is a known issue from many years back (https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/56), so unfortunately you're out of luck.
However, you could do a couple of things to get around this.

Develop your code mobile-first and inline so that the responsiveness is only needed on desktops, and if it all breaks, desktops will show the mobile layout (assuming that is preferable rather than mobiles trying to show desktop layout)

Trim your code. Unless you are using a program such as drag & drop or MJML, you should be able to slim your code down so as not to trigger the clipping behaviour (less than 101kB of code, as well as less than 16kB of styles).


